# DateTime Format in "20111122"

Tags: c#

i have this code (C#.net)

```
  DateTime time = DateTime.Now;              
  MessageBox.Show(time.ToString());
```

this shows the date in "11/22/2011 11:10:07 PM" format;

how can i show datetime in "20111122" format  using C#.net  . please advice :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify a [custom format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx):

```
MessageBox.Show(time.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `String.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd}", myDate)` where `yyyyMMdd` is taken from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx